# how can i save a dropdownlist id into a table from another table using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net, angularjs

I have a problem in my project im using angularjs see my screen shots:

**View Model**

```
 public class CustomerVM
{
    public int? OrderStatId { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public int Call4ID { get; set; }
    public int? Wk1WebID { get; set; }
    public int? Wk1OrdID { get; set; }
    }
```

**js**

```
  var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, data, $http) {

 var id = $routeParams.editId;
 $scope.lis = data.get({ id: id });

  $scope.selectTest = null;
 $scope.testTest = [];

   $http({
method: 'GET',
url: '/api/OrderStatus/',
data: { OrderStatID: 1 }
}).success(function(result) {
$scope.testTest = result;
});


$scope.selectTest1 = null;
$scope.testTest1 = [];

$http({
method: 'GET',
url: '/api/WebStatus/',
data: { WebStatID: 1 }
  }).success(function (result1) {
$scope.testTest1 = result1;
});


 $scope.save = function () {
data.update({ id: id }, $scope.lis, function () {
    $location.path('/');
});
```

};

**controller**

```
  // GET: api/CustomerLists/5


[ResponseType(typeof(CustomerList))]
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomerList(int id)
{

    var data = (from cust in db.CustomerLists
        join call24 in db.CallingList4
            on cust.CustID equals call24.CustID

        where cust.CustID == id

        select new CustomerVM
        {
            CustID = cust.CustID,
            Customer = cust.Customer,
            Call4ID = call24.Call4ID,
            Wk1WebID = call24.Wk1WebID,
            Wk1OrdID = call24.Wk1OrdID



        }).First();

    return Ok(data);

}



 // PUT: api/CustomerLists/5



[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutCustomerList(CustomerVM vm)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var cust = db.CustomerLists.Find(vm.CustID);
        var call4 = db.CallingList4.Find(vm.Call4ID);

        cust.Customer = vm.Customer;
        cust.ContactName = vm.ContactName;

        call4.Wk1OrdID = vm.Wk1OrdID;
        call4.Wk1WebID = vm.Wk1WebID;


        db.CustomerLists.Attach(cust);
        db.Entry(cust).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.CallingList4.Attach(call4);
        db.Entry(call4).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }


    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);


}
```

**Html**

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectTest" ng-model="lis.OrderStatID">
              <option ng-repeat="s in testTest" value="{{s.OrderStatID}}">                    {{s.OrderStatus}}</option>
        </select>
```

**table 1**

[image]

**table 2**

[image]

[image]

look at these screen shot, i want to save an DropdownList Id from table 1 to table 2 but im struggling can any assist. Im using angularjs. I want to save OderStatId to Wk1OrdID.

Comment: please show the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @j.wittwer can please check the updated code